# Struts.xml vs. struts.xml

Tags: struts2, action-mapping

I am new to Struts2 and I am working on a simple project that helps me to learn. I started with my `Struts.xml` file with the `S` capitalized. When I run it, I get my web page as expected with a couple fields and a submit button. When I fill them in and click submit, I get a 404 error saying:

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [MyAction] associated with context path [/MyProject]
```

I did some research and found a suggestion to change `Struts.xml` to `struts.xml` just by changing the `s` from lowercase to uppercase. When I did this and ran my project, I no longer even get to my first page. I just get the 404 error as it's trying to look for my `index.jsp`. Any ideas on why changing `struts.xml` to lowercase is causing more problems than it's fixing?
My `struts.xml` file is in `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes`. My `index.jsp` in under `WebContent`.

Here is my `struts.xml` code

```
<strtus>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="MyAction"
            class="com.Foo.MyAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/showTable.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</strtus>
```

Comment: Post your `struts.xml`, do you have any errors with it?

Comment: Can you post errors you are facing in backend log file?

Comment: How do I look at those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struts.xml file should be in src folder.
So change the file location to ProjectName/src with the file name struts.xml not Struts.xml.

Thanks,
Amit Kumar

Comment: Surprisingly this worked. I was loosely basing my program off a tutorial from [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/) which suggested to put the file where I did. This post explains that there shouldn't really be a difference at least as I understand it. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971528/path-of-struts-xml-and-web-xml).

Comment: @SarahLaMont It's not surprising at all; the `struts.xml` file should live at the root of the classpath. In a Maven project it should be in `src/main/resources`. If you're not using Maven or its equivalent, the `src` directory is adequate, but dealing with any Java app with a large number of dependencies without something to handle dependency management will quickly become unsupportable.